# How do I use Celery to communicate with multiple separated projects?

Tags: python, celery, messagebroker

I'm trying to create an architecture that will use celery and redis as a broker and as a result backend.

Here's a part of what I'm trying to do :
[image: Architecture goal]

I've been reading the documentation of `Celery` and some articles, about subtasks, producers consumers ... But most of the articles that I've read are using functions that are in the same project. 
This is not my case, each square represents a Python project which will be run in a `Docker` later.

So my question is how can I chain actions that will go through the Client, then the API that will create a tasks that will be consumed by #1 and then by #2 and then go back to the client once it's over.

I can't use `task0.s() | task1.s() | task2.s()` because as I said, projects are splitted.

Thank you for your help :) !

Comment: Things you will learn in IT: it is easier to join things then to split them. You question on the other side is very architectural and might not fit the focus of SO. It is also very broad and the information are sparse.

Comment: Yes I agree it's easier, but for future developments it will be easier to maintain if the projects are splitted. And they were made independants on purpose. My project 1 will need more workers than my project 2. 
I prefer spent some time, even if it takes me several days to do the right thing rather than the easy thing.
Anyway, thanks for your time :)